# Remove/Avoid local notification before it triggers

Tags: ios, swift, unusernotificationcenter

I'm scheduling a local notification which repeats every weekday (Say sample every Wednesday)

```
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = notificationTitle
    content.body = notificationBody

    let currentCalendar = NSCalendar.current
        let dateComponents = currentCalendar.dateComponents([.weekOfMonth], from: startDate)
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: ViewController.kEveryWeekIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in

        }
```

Above code works fine, but I wanted to remove particular notification before it triggers/delivers.
Is it possible to remove like that? 
Or atleast is it possible to not to trigger notification on particular date?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could delete the notification:

1) by identifier

When you created the notification you set its identifier. You can remove the notification by passing in that identifier to the following method:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: arrayOfNotificationIds)
```

2) by date

Another option is to collate all scheduled notifications and filter them by a specific date, and then pass the ones scheduled on a specific date to the above mentioned method in order to delete them.

You can get all scheduled notifications as follows:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: {requests -> () in }
```

You may also find this helpful: to extract the trigger (and its date for filtering purposes) from a scheduled notification:

1) retrieve the notification using above methods

2) get the notification trigger.

```
let currentTrigger = currentRequest.trigger as! UNCalendarNotificationTrigger
```

3) get the date components out of the trigger

```
let dateComponents = currentTrigger.dateComponents
```

4) Use the dateComponents as you see fit

Filter away!